# Ninja trader C# code not work for loop skips

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm coding a trading strategy in NinjaTrader with C#.I'm new to C#.

It seems something wrong with my code:

```
private bool _enterLong;
private bool _enterShort;

private void SetEntrySignal()
{

   if (Slope(EMA(20), 5, 0) > -0.01 && Slope(EMA(20), 5, 0) < 0.01)
   {
      _enterLong = Close[0] > Open[0];
      _enterLong &= Open[0] > High[1];
   }
   _enterShort = Close[0] < Open[0];
   _enterShort &= Open[0] < Low[1];
}
```

Because the _enterLong signal hasn't been triggered,only short(sell) signal has been triggered.So Is any syntax wrong with this part C# code?

Comment: how about the results of this Slope() method? Maybe long is no triggered because results are always < -0.01 and > 0.01? Can you debug it?

Comment: Yes you are right!!Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only guessing here.

```
private bool _enterLong;
private bool _enterShort;

private void SetEntrySignal()
{

   if (Slope(EMA(20), 5, 0) > -0.01 && Slope(EMA(20), 5, 0) < 0.01)
   {
      _enterLong = Close[0] > Open[0];
      _enterLong &= Open[0] > High[1];
   }
   else
   {
      _enterShort = Close[0] < Open[0];
      _enterShort &= Open[0] < Low[1];
    }
}
```

Note if this is not your question, or makes no sense, i will delete